# How does the Orxify app do what not even the official TOR client for Android can?

Tags: proxy

I was looking for TOR in the Play store a while ago & did not find anything but then today I see that the official TOR site has Orbot for Android but apparently it cannot protect you unless you use apps configured to use Orbot & since I dislike messing with port settings etc. I kept searching to find an app called Orxy with a plugin called Orxify which claims to use the TOR network to anonymize all your Android traffic without any configuring.  Now is that even possible?  Or is it a false claim?  I see no real reviews on the web on Orxify and it seems they changed their name from Anonify...why change it unless they are trying to hide something?  Anybody know of this app and the validity of it's claims?

OS: 4.1
S3

Answer (score 1):

Orbot uses iptables to proxy all apps through Tor, which requires root access.

According to the description of Orxify it uses Android's native VPN mode to proxy all apps through Tor.

Apps that use the built-in Android VPN interface do not require root access. This is the primary advantage of Orxify over Orbot.

On Android 4.0 and above apps can create a native VPN connection without root access to send and receive all network traffic. In this case the Orxify app creates a VPN connection to Tor and routes the internet traffic through the VPN. This can be identified by the key icon in the status bar.

I have not used or tested this app and this explanation is based solely on my knowledge of Tor, VPNs, and the [Orxify app Play Store description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inetric.anonify).

Comment: If Orxify just uses a VPN does that mean that all the app traffic is just going through a standard VPN & not being bounced around the world at any point?

Comment: It still uses the same tor network except Android shows it as a VPN connection because that's the only way to route all traffic through tor without root. It basically just sends all data to the tor app.

Comment: Hmm...if it's so easy then why doesn't TOR do this also so one can use it properly without root?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you use VPN. 
VPN mode in android redirect all traffic to one app. 
It's then app decision how to handle it.
Orxify did this. And also integrate tor library.

Tor community try this few times but not succeeded so far.
https://github.com/guardianproject/OrbotVPN

There is also Drony. Drony also uses VPN but redirect then all to Orbot app.

But apps are not open source. 
This is not good starting point to be recognized by Tor community as safe to use.

by Drony support

Comment: Who is not open source?